# How to read a text file?

Tags: go

I'm trying to read "file.txt" and put the contents into a variable using Golang. Here is what I've tried...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Print(file)
}
```

The file gets read successfully and the return from *os.Open* returns a type of ***os.File**

Comment: The result of the function above outputs &{0xc082016240}

Answer (score 134, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

```
file, err := os.Open("file.txt")
fmt.print(file)
```

The reason it outputs &{0xc082016240}, is because you are printing the pointer value of a file-descriptor (`*os.File`), not file-content. To obtain file-content, you may `READ` from a file-descriptor.

---

To read all file content(in bytes) to memory, `ioutil.ReadAll`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err = file.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()


  b, err := io.ReadAll(file)
  fmt.Print(b)
}
```

But sometimes, if the  file size is big, it might be more memory-efficient to just read in chunks: buffer-size, hence you could use the implementation of `io.Reader.Read` from `*os.File`

```
func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err = file.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()


    buf := make([]byte, 32*1024) // define your buffer size here.

    for {
        n, err := file.Read(buf)

        if n > 0 {
            fmt.Print(buf[:n]) // your read buffer.
        }

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("read %d bytes: %v", n, err)
            break
        }
    }

}
```

Otherwise, you could also use the standard util package: `bufio`, try `Scanner`. A `Scanner` reads your file in tokens: separator.

By default, scanner advances the token by newline (of course you can customise how scanner should tokenise your file, learn from here [the bufio test](https://golang.org/src/bufio/example_test.go)).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
    "bufio"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err = file.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for scanner.Scan() {             // internally, it advances token based on sperator
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())  // token in unicode-char
        fmt.Println(scanner.Bytes()) // token in bytes

    }
}
```

Lastly, I would also like to reference you to this awesome site: [go-lang file cheatsheet](http://www.devdungeon.com/content/working-files-go). It encompassed pretty much everything related to working with files in go-lang, hope you'll find it useful.

Comment: you miss the import `bufio` and it should be `bufio.NewScanner(file)` instead of `bufio.NewScanner(fd)`, and the other hand, it works perfectly!! thank you.

Comment: @CristianChaparroA. It's been fixed! thank you :)

Comment: The very helpful answer, though I have the question:- do we need slicing in `buf[:n]` in the statement `fmt.Print(buf[:n])`.  ....For me just  `fmt.Print(buf)` worked well. ............

Comment: `f.Close()` change to `file.Close()`

Comment: Should be `fmt.Print(file)` in the first example vs `fmt.print(file)`