# How to read a Golang file using Golang?

Tags: go

i want know if there`s  a way to read a go and get the content from that file using go.

for example: I have a file called car.go and inside this file has a struct called Car, i want to read that struct Car properties.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser#ParseFile

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achive exactly ? Whether you're trying to parse go code for some reason or inspect type dynamically at runtime, it will raise different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I am getting it right, but if you are trying to use struct that is defined in other file, then you can import the struct in your current file.

**Note** - If both the files are inside a comman module, then you don't need to import, you can directly use all structs condition that their first letter is capital.

Refer this for better understanding of import - [link](https://go.dev/doc/code#ImportingLocal)

In case you want to read file of any extensions, you can refer this thread - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111777/how-to-read-a-text-file)

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can parse go files with a go package. Take a look at this example: https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#example-CommentMap